# How can I test Rx oberservable in async scenario?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, system.reactive, reactive-programming, observable

I have broken down the problem into an example.
The processor performs an async operation and publishes the result via an Rx observable.

```
public class Tests
{
    [Test]
    public async Task Receiving_an_async_result_should_succeed()
    {
        var p = new Processor();

        p.Process("message");

        var res = await p.Results;

        res.Should().NotBeNullOrEmpty();
    }
}

public class Processor
{
    private readonly ReplaySubject<string> _subject = new ReplaySubject<string>();

    public async void Process(string message)
    {
        try
        {
            // Fake some async processing here!
            var r = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => message.Reverse().ToString());

            _subject.OnNext(r);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _subject.OnError(e);
        }
    }

    public IObservable<string> Results { get { return _subject; } }
}
```

The problem here is that I don't know how to set up the test case correctly. It seems that the awaited result never arrives!

Comment: Process and REsults are not related why you are expecting when PRocess is finished then the reuslts shall also be finished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Results is an `IObservable<T>` - therefore it is not finished until it has sent an `OnCompleted()`. This is why your await is not returning.

I suspect you want to wait for just the first result (looks like you intend to call `Process` repeatedly) - so if you change this line:

```
var res = await p.Results;
```

To this:

```
var res = await p.Results.Take(1);
```

You will have more luck.

Comment: Good stuff, there's also a `FirstAsync()` introduced in current versions of Rx that behaves similarly to `Take(1)`, except it doesn't have the ugly magic number. I keep forgetting about it though!